# Pandoc: How do I iterate over TOC child elements?

Tags: bootstrap-4, pandoc

I am looking to build a custom Pandoc template, in which I scrollspy over the TOC elements. However, I can't figure out how to iterate over TOC child elements, such that I can apply styling. Is this possible with Pandoc?

Comment: I guess you could always add some JavaScript...

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: you can't, at least currently. The table-of-contents variable used when populating the template is just a string without any structure, so there is no way to iterate over it.

The only possibility I see is to use a [filter](https://pandoc.org/scripting.html), or a [lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html), to generate the ToC yourself. Save the resulting ToC in a metadata field, e.g. `mytoc`, and use that in your template.  This is probably a bit tedious, but would give you full control over content and styles used in the table of contents.